i get an error when i want to build my docker image
 Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
67.41   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
67.41   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
67.41
67.41   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
67.41   │ exit code: 1
67.41   ╰─> [23 lines of output]
67.41       running egg_info
67.41       creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b9v2ncih/psycopg2.egg-info
67.41       writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b9v2ncih/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
67.41       writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b9v2ncih/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
67.41       writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b9v2ncih/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
67.41       writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-b9v2ncih/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
67.41
67.41       Error: pg_config executable not found.
67.41
67.41       pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
67.41       containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
67.41       option:
67.41
67.41           python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
67.41
67.41       or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
67.41
67.41       If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
67.41       'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
67.41
67.41       For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
67.41       <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
67.41
67.41       [end of output]
67.41
67.41   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
67.43 error: metadata-generation-failed
67.43
67.43 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
67.43 ╰─> See above for output.
67.43
67.43 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
67.43 hint: See above for details.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install -r req.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

i created a file(req.txt) which has my packages and set that file for my docker for installing those packages to my image. when i run the command for building the docker,
i get a error in installing the packages
ERROR [django 6/6] RUN pip install -r req.txt

Check your req.txt if you have psycopg-binary
pip install psycopg-binary

